# question starting with "but"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

If we started a sentence with "but", should we use word order of main or subordinate clause?

> ... But can the above mentioned technique be also used in this situation? ...

or

> ... But can be the above mentioned technique also used in this situation? ...

Comment: Hello, Riko. This question is more suitable for the sister site, ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Riko.

The *but* doesn't make any difference to the grammar.

But in any case, I cannot think of *any* context in which the order in your second example would be grammatical.

When you invert a clause with an auxiliary verb

> [The above-mentioned technique] [can] be used ...

you swap the subject and the auxiliary:

> [Can] [the above-mentioned technique] be used

The infinitive (*be* in this example) does not move.

Answer (score 1):

Riko. Hello again :-)

> But can the above-mentioned technique also be used in this situation?
>   ...

Your second alternative would not be considered grammatical.